# Issue with adding gesture options to Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I have just started using Hammer JS for the first time and am going through their getting started page (https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started)

This is the code I have:

```
        var el = $('#drag ul');
        var hammertime1 = Hammer(el,{
                drag_block_vertical:true,
                drag_lock_to_axis: true
            })
        .on("drag", function(ev) {
            if(ev.gesture.direction == 'left' || ev.gesture.direction == 'right') {
                $(this).css('left',ev.gesture.deltaX);
            };
            ev.gesture.preventDefault();
        });
```

However, the drag locks dont seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE

Got it working by adding lock_to_axis on both functions

Comment: I find a possible error in your code: you should construct the hammer object with the 'new' operator, like this: var hammertime1 = new Hammer({...});